# How do I test receiving grade information from third party applications on Open Edx?

Tags: zoom-sdk, openedx, lti

I integrated Zoom on the Open Edx platform. You can successfully create a meeting. But I only briefly configured it, and in the configuration process I found that some configurations were related to scores. I want to know what these configurations do. How to use the third-party application Zoom to return grade information to Open Edx.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvmno.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11MKR.png)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.